# How to access globar variable with nested functions ? javascript

Tags: javascript, global-variables, javascript-objects, nested-function

I have the bellow class:

```
var CasperInstance = function(casper) {

    this.casper = casper;
    var x = casper.selectXPath;
    var parent = this;


    this.then = function(callback) {

        return this.casper.then(function() {

            parent.casper.evaluate(function() {

                try {
                    x('//*[@id="email_address"]');
                } catch (err) {

                    //ReferenceError: Can't find variable: x
                    console.log(err);
                }

            });

        });

    };


};
```

When i try to call the x() , I get this error:`ReferenceError: Can't find variable: x` .

however x is global variable I can access from any nested function . right ?

Thank you

Comment: Try window.x and check spelling and capatals

Comment: in order to get a better answer, you could provide a fiddle with a minimal problem and the expected behaviour

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a common problem when using things like `Casper`.

Normally a javascript function would capture `x` in a closure and it would be available to functions within the scope. That's what it looks like should happen here. But the problem is that `casper.evaluate()` specifically avoids this -- the point of `evaluate()` is to use the context of the current page DOM. Which means you only have access to the scope of the page. The documentation is actually very good on this point:

http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#evaluate

You aren't going to be able to pass a function into `casper.evaluate`. `evaluate()` is basically calling phantomjs's `evaluate()`, so their [docs](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/evaluate.html) are helpful:

> Note: The arguments and the return value to the evaluate function must be a simple primitive object. The rule of thumb: if it can be serialized via JSON, then it is fine.

So you are kind of stuck and will need to find a different way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

`x` is not a global variable, it is local to `casperInstance` function.  I suggest

```
this.casper.selectXPath('//*[@id="email_address"]');
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it doesn't work , I received this error : TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.casper.selectXPath')